# Macro to extract data from Word table to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Good morning,

I need a Macro in Excel that can extract data from specific tables, columns and rows in my Word doc.

So here is my Excel file and in the 2nd row down I have stipulated which table, row and column data I need returned to that cell from my Word doc (also shown).

[image: Excel file]

[image: Word doc page 1]

[image: Word doc page 2]

I am not a programmer, so I tried Quick Parts and AutoText but didn't get very far.

I would grateful for your help :)

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.  We can only comment/help on code you have already written but isn't working.

Comment: I appreciate that, thank you. I was just hoping someone could help. I have asked for some help before and someone very kindly wrote me a piece of code :)

Comment: See, for example: https://forums.excelguru.ca/threads/help-with-vba-to-extract-data-from-word-to-excel.8900/post-36586 & https://forums.excelguru.ca/threads/help-with-vba-to-extract-data-from-word-to-excel.8900/post-36594 Since your data don't appear to all be in one table - or contiguous - the code will need some tweaking.

Comment: Thank you but I wouldn't know where to start. If I post my original question above on Excel Guru do you think they can write me a Macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
Sub WordToExcel()
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim x As Integer
Dim strFilename As String
Dim strFolder As String
Dim temp As String

Set wdApp = New Word.Application
'initialise counter
x = 1
'search for first file in directory
strFolder = "C:\Test\"
strFilename = Dir(strFolder & "*.doc*")
'amemd folder name
Do While strFilename <> ""
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(strFolder & strFilename)
temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text 'read word cell
Range("A2").Offset(x, 0) = temp
temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text 'read word cell
Range("A2").Offset(x, 1) = temp
'etc
temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 3).Range.Text 'read word cell
Range("A2").Offset(x, 2) = temp
temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 4).Range.Text 'read word cell
Range("A2").Offset(x, 3) = temp

wdDoc.Close
x = x + 1
strFilename = Dir
Loop
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Setup:

[image]

Or...you can try this very primitive solution...

```
Sub ImportFromWord()

  'Activate Word Object Library

  Dim WordDoc As Word.Document

  Set WordApp = CreateObject("word.application") ' Open Word session

  WordApp.Visible = False 'keep word invisible
  Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Word.doc") ' open Word file

  'copy third row of first Word table
  WordDoc.Tables(1).Rows(3).Range.Copy

  'paste in Excel
  Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

  WordDoc.Close 'close Word doc
  WordApp.Quit ' close Word

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So my Word doc is called application.doc Where in the code to I need to insert this? Also is it the names in green surrounded by " " where I need to put in my field names, like *Full Name / Company?

Comment: Application.GetOpenFilename will dynamically open the file that you select. Also, insert DocVariable...
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-store-and-retrieve-variables-in-word-documents-3a912a35-42a0-7a28-7f2d-787ed6afb566

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I forgot one thing. Hit Alt+F11 > Tools > References > Microsoft Word xx.x Object Library > OK

Comment: Ok done that and now the Macro runs but is circling saying Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action. I cancelled after waiting a while an now get an error message saying Method 'Open' of objects 'Documents' failed.

Comment: I have changed FirstName on the Macro to be Full Name / Company, which is the Header in cell A1. I have changed 'LastName' to be 'Site Name & Address', which is the Header in cell F1. Should this return any values under the headings A1 to F1 into A2 to F2? Because at the moment it circles for a while and still getting same error as above which I posted. Does that mean that in fact these are Tables not DocVariables?

Comment: In the Word Doc, hit Alt+F9. If those are DocVariables, you will see them exposed with Alt+F9. If it's a table, click the cross-hairs in the upper left, and the entire table will be selected.

Comment: Ok so these are definitely tables ASH. Please could you adapt the code so it picks the data in the specified table, rows and headers of my Word doc, as per my original post?

Comment: I just updated my original post.

Comment: Hi ASH, firstly thank you so much I really appreciate your help and time :) I have made an amendment to specify the folder and file name in the top bit of code you asked me to try. At the moment nothing happens and the data in row 2 remains the same starting with cell A2, as per my screenshot in my original post for Excel.

Comment: 'search for first file in directory
strFolder = "C:\Users\brendan.ramsey\OneDrive - Ofcom\Objectives\Brendan's Objectives 2022-23\Licence calls"
strFilename = Dir(strFolder & "application.doc")
'amemd folder name
Do While strFilename <> ""

Comment: Do i have to change Do While strFilename <> "" ?

Comment: I guess you need the hit F8 over and over and over, and see where the code fails for you. It works fine for me.

Comment: Got funny feeling here. When I hit Alt+F9 it has exposed DocVariables I think. But these are within tables. Does this mean I have to alter the code further?

Comment: Here are a bunch of files that demonstrate how to integrate Word and Excel. 

https://www.mediafire.com/folder/gh6vz3otyx51u/word_to_excel

Get one or two easy samples working, and then you get more and more sophisticated things working.

Comment: ASH thank you so much, got it working using the simpler version of code above and adding to it :)

Comment: Good stuff! Keep learning, growing, developing, and doing amazing things!!

Comment: Thanks ASH :) One quick question before I wrap up. When I try and run the Excel Macro on some Word docs I get run time error code '4605' 'The method or property is not available because no text is selected'. Do you know what that means please?

Comment: Not sure. Google it. Also, 'on error resume next' will handle any errors that popup, and your code will keep running to the end of the process.

Comment: Yeah tried googling it but not getting anywhere. It seems to be happening with quite a few Word docs I am trying to extract data from. It must be a formatting thing. I don't know. It is corrupting the tables in the Word documents after running the Macro too.

Comment: Not sure. Again, you can add 'On Error Resume Next' close to the top of your Module. Some people will say it's dangerous, because it hides/masks all errors, so you can't debug anything, but at least your code will run until it's done. Or...in the VBA Editor (Alt+F11), select your variable, then right-click, and click 'Add Watch' and finally click 'OK'. Your variable will go into the Watch Window. From there, you can potentially debug the issue. If you know what you're doing, it's a great tool. If you are a novice, it may not help much. Anyway, try it, and see how far you can get with it.

Comment: I will do ASH thank you so much again 